# How to stop Videoview from playing inside a viewPager when fragment is changed

Tags: android-viewpager

I want to stop a videoView from playing inside a viewPager when the fragment is change. The problem in the code is when I change or get into the next fragment the video is still playing.

Here is the code for Main Activity class

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentStepOne(), "1");
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentStepTwo(), "2");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mFragmentList.size();
}


public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

And here is the code for the Fragment class

```
public class FragmentStepOne extends Fragment{

public FragmentStepOne() {
}


VideoView video;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_two, container,        false);

video = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.video);
video.setVideoURI(uri);

MediaController mc=new MediaController(getContext());
mc.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(mc);
video.requestFocus();



return rootView;
}
```

please help thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment override `override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean)`

because `setUserVisibleHint` is called before `onCreateView` Make sure you check if the view is not null (so that you can avoid null pointer exceptions).

Here's how I implemented mine:

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (view != null)
            if (!isVisibleToUser)
                if (videoView.isPlaying) {
                    videoView.stopPlayback()
                }
    }
```

and I am extending the Fragment `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`